# Data not getting updated in Angular when fetched from Firebase RealTime Database

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database

HTML Content is refreshed when I provide static data from firedb.service.ts but when I fetch data from firebase, I'm unable to display content.

To debug, I gave both static and firebase data. So static data gets displayed, but firebase data, thought gets logged to the console, never reaches the html of the page.

I tried adding some console.logs() to debug the code. I have also add comments along with the same to indicate the order in  which console.log() statements get executed.

firedb.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { of } from 'rxjs'; 

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class FiredbService {
  constructor(private firestore: AngularFireDatabase) { }
  public getMovies(){
    let movies;
    let dbref = this.firestore.database.ref();
    dbref.once('value', function(snapshot) {
      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        movies = childSnapshot.val();
        console.log(movies); //This prints last but page doesnt refresh
      });
    });
    console.log("Before Return") //This prints first
    console.log(movies); //This prints second as undefined
    movies = [{"title":"Inception","year":"2010"},{"title":"Inception","year":"2010"}];
    return of(movies);
  }
}
```

movie-list.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FiredbService } from '../firedb.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'movie-list',
  templateUrl: './movie-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movie-list.component.css']
})

export class MovieListComponent implements OnInit {
  movies;
  constructor(private firestore: FiredbService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.firestore.getMovies().subscribe(data => this.movies = 
      data);
    console.log("Inside Component"); //This prints third
    console.log(this.movies);  //This prints fourth, static content from firedb.service
  }
}
```

Debugger Console

```
Before Return      (from firedb.service)
undefined          (from firedb.service)
Inside Component   (from the movie-list.component)
[{…}, {…}]         (from the movie-list.component)
[1: {…}, 2: {…}, 3: {…}, 4: {…}, ......., 10000:{…}]  (from firedb.service)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of angular change detection strategy.You need to import ChangeDetectorRef from @angular/core in the component. Then you need to inject that from the constructor. Once you get the data from firebase you need to call the detectChanges() method.

Sample Constructor code

```
constructor(
    private _changeDetectionRef: ChangeDetectorRef
    ) 
    {

     }
```

Sample http call with change detection

```
getPractices() {

    this._clientService.getList(0, 100)
      .subscribe(result => {

        if (result != null && result.items.length > 0) {
          this.practices = result.items;
        }
       this._changeDetectionRef.detectChanges();
      })
  }
```